# How to obtain a isometric immersion of $T^n$ (the flat torus) into $\mathbb{R}^{2n}?$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to construct an isometric immersion of $T^n := S^1\times\ldots \times S^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^{2n}.$

I am considering The flat Torus, i.e., on each $S^1$ I am considering the metric induced by $\mathbb{R}^2$ and on $T^n$ the product metric.

The way I am trying to obtain this is to define the map:

$$f : T^n \to \mathbb{R}^{2n} $$
$$f(z_1,\ldots,z_n) := (a_1,b_1,\ldots,a_n,b_n),$$
where $z_j \equiv (a_j,b_j) \equiv a_j + ib_j$ and $|z_j| = 1.$
Here $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Once I show that this map is an immersion the claim follows pulling-back the metric of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}.$

Is it ok?

I am not sure about this argument once I can not give an clear statement that $f$ is an immersion without calculating on coordinates charts.

Comment: My bad, I am assuming the flat torus.

Comment: The torus with the product metric where I am considering the metric induced by $\mathbb{R}^2$ on each $S^1.$

Comment: Is your question 'Is it ok?'. If so, the answer is yes. In practice, what you do is to 'push-forward' the vectors (computing $\langle df_x(X),df_x(Y)\rangle$), instead of  pulling-back the metric.

Comment: You should really change "onto" to "into" in the title.

Comment: @Max, you are right. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$Your $z_{j}$ notation is potentially vexing because the $z_{j}$ are unit complex numbers rather than real numbers. You might instead pick local coordinates $\theta_{j}$ on the torus so that $z_{j} = \exp(i\theta_{j})$ for each $j$, and define
$$
f(\theta_{1}, \dots, \theta_{n})
  = (\cos\theta_{1}, \sin\theta_{1}, \dots, \cos\theta_{n}, \sin\theta_{n}).
$$
It's elementary to show that the (vector-valued) partial derivatives $df(\theta)(\mathbf{e}_{j}) = \dd f/\dd \theta_{j}$ form an orthonormal set at each point, so that $f$ is a local isometry (and, particularly, is an immersion).

Comment: nice approach. My approach was, show that the jacobian matrix has a submatrix of rank $2$ and then calculate the metric. The claim follows.